# Getting length, id and name of "input" tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get length, id and name of all `input` tags inside a `div` having class name only?

HTML:

```
<div id="division1" class="clonedInput kudd">
    <div class="set1">
        <label for="eee">Name</label>
        <input id="ee2" type="text" value="" name="ee2">
        <input id="ee3" type="text" value="" name="ee3">
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.set1 > input').attr('id').length;
$('.set1 > input').attr('id'); //No output
```

Comment: use jquery $.each methd . $('.set1 > input').each(function(){});

http://jsfiddle.net/agenhvdh/1/

Comment: `$('.set1 > input').attr('id')` works (showing first `input` ID) inside `document.ready`: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xnj9grpa/).

Answer (score 2):

You can to use `each`:

```
$('.set1 input').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this); // Caching

    var id = $this.attr('id');
    var name = $this.attr('name');
    var length = $this.val().length;

    console.log('ID: ' + id + '    Name: ' + name + '    Length: ' + length);
});
```

> A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via their named properties.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: @Regent `how to get length, id and name of all "input" tags` is the question

Comment: @Regent Wrong choice of words! Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.set1 input').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Please don't put opening braces on their own line, but right after the `function()`.. An accidental extra newline could turn have javascript add `;`  to make statements where you don't intend them. It will  *never* be  the case here, because of the parentheses of the `each`-call, but putting braces on there own line is bound to put you in trouble one day.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling well, will you suggest to put `{` at the same line with `if`? By the way, since `function` is passed as parameter, making mix of `{}` and `()`, the better way is to declare function before its using, isn't it?

Comment: @regent: you don't have to take my word for it. Douglas Crockford [has excellent reasons](https://youtu.be/hQVTIJBZook?t=30m40s) why `{` should be on the *right* in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.set1 input').each(function() {
var length= $(this).val().length;
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
 var name= $(this).attr('name');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.map()` in jquery

```
var map = $('.set1 input').map(function() {
    return { 'id' : $(this).attr('id'),
             'name' :  $(this).attr('name')
           }
}); 
console.log(map)
```

Answer (score 1):

use jquery [$.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function to get all input record

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/agenhvdh/1/)

> generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate
>   over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a
>   length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated
>   by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via
>   their named properties.

JQUERY

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.set1 > input').each(function(){
     console.log($(this).attr('id') +"=="+$(this).attr('id').length);
    });

 });
```